# Move dropdown menu to the right

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, baseadapter

I work on an old Android project, I use a compileSdkVersion 16. I have put a SeekBar (a slider) in a dropdown menu. It works perfectly but my button, for displaying the dropdown menu is on the left and I want it on the right, like a parameter button in the Navigation Drawer Activity (the 3 vertically dot).

In my main activity I have thise :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
DropDown dropDown = new DropDown(this,"Controls","Power", "Tag Filter");
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(dropDown, this);
```

I use two layout, one for the button in the action bar :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Controls"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

An another one for my dropdown menu :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seekBarTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarTextView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
[...]
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know how to put my button to the right, actually it's on the left, near the application name and I want to put it on the opposite.
I have this :
[image]
But I want this :
[image]

Edit :
My gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def AAVersion = "4.3.0" // change this to your desired version, for example the latest stable: 4.2.0

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    //buildToolsVersion '25.3.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.dpdencoder.uhu"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile files('libs/jdom.jar')
    // For Hexa coding/décoding
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile files('libs/OpenApi_1.1.2.61_Common.jar')
    compile files('libs/OpenApi_1.1.2.61_IaM.jar')
    compile files('libs/OpenApi_1.1.2.61_IoT.jar')
}
```

Comment: cant you add a relative layout and put both inside? then align them

Answer (score 0):

**Toolbar** is advanced version of **ActionBar**. Use Toolbar instead of ActionBar.
Customize the Toolbar as your wish. And set it as ActionBar.

```
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

Don't forget to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme as your activity theme.

More info about Toolbar: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: It doesn't exist on the sdk 25 and the buildToolsVersion 25. I use compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'

Comment: use com.android.support:appcompat-v7. You will get it.

Comment: I put compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2' in my dependencies but I have the following message Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2

Comment: You are using sdk 25 so use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` update all the support version to 25.3.1.

Comment: If you get error again post your gradle file and tell me

Comment: the package id build-tools;25.3.1

Comment: post your complete gradle file in your question

Comment: Gradle seems too old. I can give you an another idea. Remove action bar from your app use Relative layout instead. Then you can position it.